# Django url internationalization not working in production mode

Tags: django, url, internationalization

i'm programming in django 1.4 a site with multilanguage support (french and english).

Everything works fine in debug mode. Then I pass to production mode (DEBUG=False) and the urls no longer work.

Ex. : in debug mode, when I request the page /agricole/, django redirect automatically to /fr/agricole.

But in production mode, it sends a error and no longer redirect the page.

I have searched the web, check the LocaleMiddleware, like said on django documentation and everything, but it still fails.

I cannot hard code /fr/* in the templates, since it will break the multilingue support. 
And writting by hand a redirector who redirect, is not clean.

What do I miss? A template tag? a url config?

My

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.doc.XViewMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.page.CurrentPageMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.user.CurrentUserMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.toolbar.ToolbarMiddleware',
    'cms.middleware.language.LanguageCookieMiddleware',
)
```

and my url.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.conf.urls.i18n import i18n_patterns
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import RedirectView

admin.autodiscover()

import annonces.views as annonces

urlpatterns = i18n_patterns('',
    url(r'.*register/$', 'annonces.register', name='register'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'accounts/profile/$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/')),
    url(r'^favicon\.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url='static/favicon.ico')),
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'show_indexes': True}),
    (r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    (r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^longlat/(.*)$', 'annonces.longlat', name='longlat'),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
)
```

Answer (score 4):

I found problem of this issue.
if you have some middlewares that handle 404 page, then this page must retur status 404. If it will return othe status then i18n redirect will not work.

Comment: The middleware are the ones cited precedently. Are there any that you think does what you describe?

Comment: Check the http error code of /agricole/ if it differs from 404 then   you found your problem. And if you set http error to 404 it will work like in debug mode(because debug mode do not use custom 404 error pages)

Comment: You save my life, I have been tracing and debugging the issue with Mezzaine i18n , and finally your answer give me the hint. Thanks!